# Why Android does not pause a fragment whose view is completely blocked by the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

First, I am happy with my activity's `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` settings. I don't want the bottom of my screen to offer anything when the keyboard is up. Instead, I want to "pause" (or call the onPause() methods of) the fragments that are completely blocked by the soft keyboard, and then resume them back once it is out of their view.

At least I expected the fragments to do so on their own. But from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPause()), it looks like their onPause() is generally linked to their parent activity's onPause().

From the other related questions' answers here and elsewhere, I understand there is no easy way to get the state of the soft keyboard yet. And, even doing so by hook or crook, I don't want to call the onPause() and onResume() manually on each suspected fragment.

So, my practical question is: **is it possible to make any fragment self-aware when its view is blocked by the soft keyboard? If yes, how?**

And yes, I want to understand if there are any good reasons why Android does not call onPause() on fragments whose views are completely blocked, unlike it does for an activity's onPause(). I understand it does not do it even for an activity in case of the soft keyboard. But getting completely blocked (intentionally or unintentionally) by anything, like the soft keyboard, should have some impact on an active view's life cycle, I feel.

*I hope it is not gushingly marked duplicate, as I am not asking to know the state of the soft keyboard in an activity, at least directly :)*

Comment: "is it possible to make any fragment self-aware when its view is blocked by the soft keyboard?" -- not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Because of keyboard is neither activity no home screen. The same effect appears when you rollout notification bar

Comment: Good to know. But doesn't answer why it is designed so, and how to achieve what I want to achieve.